# Django - how to combine multiple filter parameters together, where the number of parameters is variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to implement a search function on Django. If my query is: "a b c", then I want to to search :

`select * from table where col LIKE '%a%' and col LIKE '%b%' and col LIKE '%c%'`

I see I can do that with

```
table.objects.filter(col__icontains('a'))
```

But how do I make this work for a,b & c. **I can't hard-code the number of parameters**. There might be a,b,c,d or any number of search terms.?

Comment: you can chain filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters or generate Q object https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: I cant hard-code the number of parameters

Comment: you don't need to, hence words generate and chain, Iain already answered below  with an example

Comment: I don't understand what 'words generate and chain' means. Can you please post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain filters on a QuerySet in a loop to get multiple `AND` filters

```
query = 'a b c'
queryset = table.objects.all()
for part in query.split():
    queryset = queryset.filter(col__icontains=part)
```